# Accessing resources embedded in jar from FXML

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am having great difficulty loading files (in my case .png's and .css's) that are located within a jar file from an fxml file.

Folder structure is quite generic, as such:

```
/com/project/client/
   main/
      client.jar
   fxml/
      client.fxml
   resources/
      image.png
```

In my fxml file I have an image. It loads the image as such:

```
<Image url="@../resources/image.png" />
```

When I run this through Eclipse, everything works perfectly. I am suspecting this is because Eclipse create a bin\ directory where it exports the project everything as .class files in actual folders. The moment you attempt to compile this to a jar and run it, everything fails, since the fxml fails to realise that I require it to load files that are contained within the jar itself.

I have searched far and wide, but I could not find anything to help me solve this issue. Does anyone here have any clue on how to solve this?

Thankyou!

Comment: Why don't you just give those some id in the FXML and then load it on the controller?

Comment: It would mean that viewing the fxml file by itself would produce obscure results with no css styling and empty images. It _could_ work ofcourse, but it is not optimal! I thought that a tech like javafx would have functionality such that I do not need to 'hack' around, applying css in code etc.

Comment: What's the location of the image.png inside the JAR?

Comment: Opening the jar in 7-zip, the file is located as to be expected: in com\project\client\resources\image.png

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<Image url="/com/project/client/resources/image.png"/>
```

Comment: Very interesting... it works! Kind off. It works through Eclipse, it works through exporting as a jar. However, opening the fxml directly through Scene Builder results in a failure to find the image. Thank-you for this!... But is there any way to get it to work through scene builder too?

Comment: No clue. I don't use Scene Builder (much)... Not sure why it would fail there.